# C: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type singly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, linked-list

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

/* Function prototypes */
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item);
#endif
```

**list.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodeStruct {
    int item;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
};
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {
    struct nodeStruct *node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeStruct));
    if (node == NULL) {return NULL;}
    node->item = item;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

**Main.c:**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodeStruct *one = List_createNode(1);
while(one != NULL) {
    printf("%d", one->item); //error
    one= one->next; //error
}
```

Error: `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type printf("%d", one->item);`

The error is at `one->item`, I have tried several combinations to dereference, but does not seem to work. What's the right approach?

Updated:

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

    struct nodeStruct {
    int item;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
};
/* Function prototypes */
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item);
#endif
```

Now the error is, `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct nodeStruct’
  struct nodeStruct *node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeStruct));`
 From my list.c file.

Comment: Did you include the definition of `struct nodeStruct` in the main .c file? Also, you probably want to remove the * in `one =  *one->next;`. Oh, and modifying `one` may leak memory.

Comment: @EOF that's not the problem because other methods work.

Comment: So the definition of `struct nodeStruct` is, in fact, **not available to main()**. Put the *definition* of `struct nodeStruct` into `list.h`. Hint: It's currently in `list.c`.

Comment: ...And now you also need to `#include "list.h"` in `list.c`.

Comment: Actually, where's your `int main()` function? It's not in the `main.c` you've posted

Comment: @EOF I just left it out because I thought it would be obvious. It's actually there. Thank you for your help, it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of couple of ways:

1. Put the definition of `struct` in a header file and `#include` the header file in `main.c`.
2. Add couple of functions

   ```
   int getNodeItem(struct nodeStruct* node)
   {
      return node->item;
   }

   struct nodeStruct* getNextNode(struct nodeStruct* node)
   {
      return node->next;
   }
   ```

   and call the functions from `main`.

   ```
   while (one != NULL) {
      printf("%d", getNodeItem(one));
      one = getNextNode(one);
   }
   ```

Comment: #1 did not work. However, #2 did. Why can't I straight out use printf?

Comment: @Aaron: Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @Aaron, there is no reason why #1 won't work. If you can update your post with additional info and updated code, we can figure that out.

Comment: @EOF Running gdb from ubuntu

Comment: @Aaron: `gdb` is a debugger. I assume you mean `gcc`?

Comment: @EOF My bad, yes GCC with -std=c99 option.

Comment: @Aaron: Is the definition of `struct nodeStruct` **before** the `main()`-function?

Comment: @EOF yes, they are placed in separate files. With `main` file including the header file. Do you want this information posted?

Comment: @Aaron: You should probably post all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include "list.h"` in `list.c`.  When `gcc` tries to compile the latter, the local invocation of the compiler doesn't know about the `struct nodeStruct` because its definition has not been included in the local file.

Note: this is based on your update in which `struct nodeStruct` is defined in `list.h`.